# How to set numbers below the seek bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set the numbers from 1 to 10 to show the progress of seek bar. But it is not looking perfectly. Please help to make the layout like below image

[image]

Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/twentyone_dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/eighteen_dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.1"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.2"
                            android:text="2"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.2"
                            android:text="3"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.1"
                            android:text="4"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.2"
                            android:text="5"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.3"
                            android:text="6"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.8"
                            android:text="7"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1.2"
                            android:text="8"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="9"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.95"
                            android:text="10"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Is there any library or any simplest method to do this?

Comment: according to my exp. you should better make custom one, coz if you proper place in android 5 or 6 in android 4 will look bad. and if you place numbers correct in android 4 then in 5 or 6 will look bad. the best way will be make custom one, coz in different android are different schemas for this element.

Comment: @StepanMaksymov True, but what do you mean by custom. Can you please give any example or hint to do this.

Comment: for example use any from github that not changes its style between android versions, then you will be able to proper set numbers below it )

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best solution is to not reinvent the wheel. There are some interesting github projects that will help you create seekbars (with a better design and user experience):

- [Crystal Range Seekbar](https://github.com/syedowaisali/crystal-range-seekbar)
- [Range Seek Bar](https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar)
- [Discrete Seek Bar](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar)

I have used these ones on many projects. They are easy to implement and to integrate with your project and allows customization.